# How can I serialise a recursive function?

Tags: python, reflection, recursion, closures, introspection

Suppose I have a function that is recursive through its closure:

```
def outer():
    def fact(n):
        return 1 if n == 0 else n * fact(n - 1)
    return fact
```

I now want to serialize the function and reconstruct it using `types.FunctionType`:

```
import pickle, marshal, copyreg, types

def make_cell(value):
    return (lambda: value).__closure__[0]

def make_function(*args):
    return types.FunctionType(*args)

copyreg.pickle(types.CodeType,
    lambda code: (marshal.loads, (marshal.dumps(code),)))
copyreg.pickle(type((lambda i=0: lambda: i)().__closure__[0]),
    lambda cell: (make_cell, (cell.cell_contents,)))
copyreg.pickle(types.FunctionType,
    lambda fn: (make_function, (fn.__code__, {}, fn.__name__, fn.__defaults__, fn.__closure__)))

buf = pickle.dumps(outer())
fn = pickle.loads(buf)
```

This works fine for ordinary closures, but with `fact` it results in infinite recursion as `pickle` attempts to serialise `fact` within its closure.  The usual way to handle recursive data structures in `pickle` is to memoise the object between construction and initialisation, but `function` objects are immutable, as are `fn.__closure__` (a tuple), and cell objects:

```
>>> cell = (lambda i=0: lambda: i)().__closure__[0]
>>> cell.cell_contents = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: attribute 'cell_contents' of 'cell' objects is not writable
```

Presumably the language has to do something similar when constructing recursive functions within normal code, as again the function object isn't available to place in its closure until it's been constructed.  Is there some magic to building recursive functions that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not a python expert, but isn't serialization about preserving state?  There's no state to be saved here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The function object returned by the parent function is a *new* object. It's state is the closure, which *may* contain more data.

Comment: A closure is just a *reference* to the original variable. The closure first can refer to a name that is empty, so `fact` being an empty cell at first. Then *after* the function is built, `fact` is bound to the new function. There is no problem there as far as Python is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closure binds to a *free variable*, not it's value. For a self-referencing closure, all Python needs to do is create a closure for the free `fact` name first (not yet bound to anything), create the function object with the closure, and then bind `fact` to that object.

As such, you need to combine creating a closure and a function into the same outer function, such that you create a closure to the name the function is going to be bound to:

```
def create_closure_and_function(*args):
    func = None
    def create_function_closure():
         return func

    closure = create_function_closure.__closure__
    func = types.FunctionType(*args[:-1] + [closure])
    return func
```

To make this work with unpickling you'd have to loop over the closure argument (`args[-1]`) and detect where there is a recursion, and replace that one item with `create_function_closure.__closure__[0]`, I suppose.

Comment: That's it; I was trying too hard to separate creating the closure from setting the value of its cell.  It's a bit fiddly trying to do everything in the same function scope, but you can capture the scope of the cell using a generator or another nested function (with `nonlocal`).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it, in Python 3 using `nonlocal`:

```
def settable_cell():
    if False:
        x = None
    def set_cell(y):
        nonlocal x
        x = y
    return (lambda: x).__closure__[0], set_cell
```

And in Python 2 using a generator:

```
def settable_cell():
    def g():
        while True:
            x = (yield (lambda: x).__closure__[0])
    set_cell = iter(g()).send
    return set_cell(None), set_cell
```

This allows separating creating a closure cell from setting the value of its free variable; the rest of the solution just requires some fiddling with the `pickle` memoisation facility.